# Java 2-D selection sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am preparing for an exam, and we are likely to be tasked with sorting a two dimensional array of ints.  Sorted meaning the first row, first column is the lowest and the last row, last column is the highest.

I approached the task by creating a 1-D array, and then populating it with all the values in the 2d array.  Then, I passed it through a sorting method.  Finally, I wrote each value of the sorted array back into the 2d array and returned it.

This sort of worked, as you can see from the output below.  I am confused as to where my process is breaking down, I would appreciate any input.

**Input:**

int[][] nums = {{1,5,9},{8,9,3},{0,7,6}};

**output:**

0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 1

```
public int[][] sort2D(int[][]nums){
    int[] temp = new int[((nums.length+1)*(nums.length+1))];//make one long array
    for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++){                      //populate
        int counter = 0;                                    //indices for long array
        for(int j = 0; j<nums[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println(temp[counter]);
            temp[counter] = (int)nums[i][j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    temp = sort(temp);                                      //sort it (verified code)


    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){                     //reverse the above process
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<nums.length; j++){
            nums[i][j] = temp[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I think you're doing wrong is this:

```
int[] temp = new int[((nums.length+1)*(nums.length+1))];//make one long array
```

nums.length +1 = 4 in your case. you are copying your 3*3 array into a 4*4 array.
This has the funny effect of adding 5 0's to your result. (temp[9] till temp[15] will be 0 filled)
After you sort, these 0's will show up

the place where your code breaks down is:

```
for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++){                      //populate
>>  int counter = 0;                                    //indices for long array
    for(int j = 0; j<nums[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(temp[counter]);
        temp[counter] = (int)nums[i][j];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

You initialize the counter to 0 every time you go through one of your outer arrays.
this means that on the 3rd pass (last array) you overwrite temp[0], temp[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and temp[2] with nums[2][0], nums[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), nums[2][2]

I assume in your actual code, you do

```
int counter = 0;                                    //indices for long array
for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++){                      //populate
    for(int j = 0; j<nums[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(temp[counter]);
        temp[counter++] = (int)nums[i][j];
    }
}
```

You could also use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), especially if you know the length and suchlike.

Comment: Thank you Joeblade, this worked.  I replaced "nums.length....." with 9 and got the expected result.  I'll have to find a cleaner way to get a proper value for the array size.

Comment: arrays.length is already the right way to get an array length. (the +1 is not needed) however probably to get the full length you'd do something like "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) { total += nums[i].length; }